# Selenium: Chrome starting, instead of IE

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

I have been working on project based on Chrome.
Today I started another project. The browser in that project must be IE.

I have following lines of code and after execution I get:

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.35.528161.

Do you know how to change the browser to IE?

```
package sodir;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import java.io.File;

public class SodirRejestracja {



    public static void main(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        WebDriver d=new InternetExplorerDriver();
        d.get("http://google.com");

    }
}
```

Comment: Am I right that you get "Starting Chrome Driver" in your console and the actual browser that is started up is Chrome?

Comment: Yes, i used chrome in another project, in this i want to use IE, but after run code above - chrome is starting, instead of IE

Comment: Right click on the new project and then run it. And check which browser is open.

Comment: 2 classes with 'main' in them, and you are running the wrong one;